# How do I set watir-chrome to use a specific profile so I can use stored cookies

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code, I need to use a stored cookie so I can avoid having to answer random security questions.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for advise.

```
pdate = `/Users/XXXX/lab2/cpb/CBTprevDate.pl`
download_directory = "/Users/XXXX/lab2/cpb"
puts download_directory
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = download_directory

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 600 # seconds ?~@~S default is 60
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile, :http_client => client, :switches => %w[--user-data-dir=/Users/XXXX/lab2/cwm/Default]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using watir-webdriver Cookies API

```
b.goto 'http://yourwebsite.com'
b.cookies.clear
b.cookies.add 'SESSION', 'value'
```

Comment: I am finding little out there on cookie.add or how to use it with an existing cookie file.  I wanted to use a custom profile with chrome like you can with firefox?  So that way I can used already saved cookies?  Is there a way to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use custom profile. Instead, just view your cookies in Chrome (http://www.wikihow.com/View-Cookies) and add each pair before test.

Comment: Thank you Mr. p0deje.  I figured it out with your help.  Bit slow being new to this and all.  Again Thank you for your answer.